# jquery when element in view

Tags: jquery, viewport

I am creating a custom slider in jquery, and would like to detect when a certain slide is in view.

Here is what i have so far:

**jQuery**

```
function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 350, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul li').removeClass('inview');
            $('#slider ul li:first').addClass('inview');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');

        });
    };

function inView() {
        if( $('li').hasClass('inview') ) {

            if ($('.inview').find('#cycler').length) {

                 console.log('has a child');

            }
        }
    };

    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
        inView();

    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="slider" style="background:#e0e4e8;">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">></a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>
  <ul>


<li>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/af2.jpg" alt="" width="1800" height="700" />
        <div id="cycler">
            <img class="active" id="showfirst"  src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/af2.jpg" alt="" width="1800" height="700" />
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/af2b.jpg" alt="" width="1800" height="700" />
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/af2c.jpg" alt="" width="1800" height="700" />    
        </div>
</li>

<li>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/af3.jpg" alt="" width="1800" height="700" />
</li>

<li>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/af1.jpg" alt="" width="1800" height="700" />
</li>


    </ul>
</div>
```

The above adds a console log when `a.control_prev`is clicked.

The issue i have is when it is clicked the console.log is added to the slide after the desired one.

Is it possible to achieve the above without using any viewport plugins etc?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: are u animating slider in moveLeft() function?

Comment: hi, yes it will navigate to the next slide

Comment: Can u share some HTML structure & animation code?

Comment: try calling `inView()` before `moveLeft()`

Comment: hi, that has the same effect, thanks anyway!